# Bootstrap 3 popover scroll doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

HTML

```
<div class="pop-div">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="<strong>Notifiche</strong>" data-html="true" data-content="Notification 1<hr />Notification 2<hr />Notification 3 <hr />Notification 4">Notifications</a>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({placement: 'bottom'});

        //hide popover when click outside
        $('body').on('click', function (e) {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    $(this).popover('hide');
                }
            });
        });
```

CSS

```
.pop-div .popover-content {
height: 50px;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

}

I have this popover in the code above. I'm trying to show a scroll bar on the left of the popover content, but this code doesn't work.
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because your CSS declaration is wrong. You should separate the selectors with comma `,` :

```css
.pop-div, .popover-content {
```

not

```css
.pop-div .popover-content {
```

in this case `.pop-div` is unnessecary, you only need

```css
.popover-content {
   height: 50px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

see fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/tv5Vu/**

Comment: Yes, thank you. But now i've another mistake: in my page i've two popovers, defined in the same way. When i click in one of this, and after i click in the second, the first popover hides, and everything works fine. But when i after click again on the first popover, it seems doesn't work properly. The mouse can not click in the scroll, and the links in the popover don't work fine. I think the browser is holding open the last opened popover, even if it is hide. Any suggestion?

Comment: As I thought, the browser hold opened the last closed popover, even if it's hided, and only after having opened earlier the first popover, after the second, and finally again the first. So, the mouse can not click in the scroll, and the links in the popover don't work fine. If you had any suggestions I would be very happy.

Comment: @user84151, hey - yes, but do you have a code example? It is a common issue with popover. Maybe you can find an answer, it has been answered a lot of times, as I recall. But happy to help if you add an example to your question - or better, ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you, i've posted a new question with code in this page: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443284/bootstrap-3-popover-show-one-and-hide-others-doesnt-work): "Bootstrap 3 popover show one and hide others doesn't work"

Comment: Just in case you tried putting `scroll` in quotes - do not!